# Change the color of a font awesome icon at a click event in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am new to `Angular` and I am building a website with a wishlist for each item (star font awesome icon). My trouble is I am unable to understand how to use `ngStyle` to fill the icon color with `yellow` when a user wishes to add the item to their wishlist (when the `click` event happens).
This is a par of my `HTML` code with the `click` event:

```
<div id="wishlist" (click)="addToWishList(item)"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```

The `addToWishList(item)` function is defined in my `component` and is working as expected. I did try to provide the color in `ngStyles` attribute in `<div>` however, it sets the color beforehand rather than on the `click` event.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is this item actually an object? i'll answer with best practices according to your case.

Comment: @Mohamed.Karkotly yes it is an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you have this item you are displaying as an object, and is predefined with an `interface` or a `class` somewhere, you can go ahead to your item `interface`/`class` and add a parameter (Say for example you call it `selected`)

Now in your template you have to make the following adjustment

```
<div id="wishlist" (click)="addToWishList(item)">
  <i [ngStyle]="{ color: item.selected ? yourColor : '' }" class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

The `addToWishList()` function would go something like this

```
addToWishList(item: Item) {
    this.item.selected = !this.item.selected;
    //Your code here
}
```

this would actually enable you to toggle the status of the item, so a click would add it to whishlist, another click would remove it from whishlist (As a style), and extra proccessing is required to remove it actually from the whishlist array.

Answer (score 3):

Using [**`ngStyle`**](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle):

```html
<i
  class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x"
  aria-hidden="true"
  [ngStyle]="{ color: THE_CONDITION_YOU_HAVE ? YOUR_NEEDED_COLOR : '' }"
></i>
```

Using [**`[style.color]`**](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding#binding-to-the-style-attribute):

```html
<i
  class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x"
  aria-hidden="true"
  [style.color]="THE_CONDITION_YOU_HAVE ? YOUR_NEEDED_COLOR : ''"
></i>
```

Note that nowadays, Angular team recommends you to use style bindings rather than `NgStyle` as per documented [**here**](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding#single-and-multiple-style-binding-example):

> The NgStyle directive can be used as an alternative to direct [style] bindings. However, using the preceding style binding syntax without NgStyle is preferred because due to improvements in style binding in Angular, NgStyle no longer provides significant value, and might eventually be removed in the future.